# Eclipse RCP: How to Edit or Delete the "Editor Area" view in helloworld app

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

Hi this is really bugging me I can't find that View so I can either delete it or use it. I can't find it in plugin.xml nor extensions. To know what exactly I'm talking about it's simple : when you create new Hello world project in RCP it's there when you create new view it's still there.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it !!,

In Perspective.java 
insert this line:

```
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
    layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false); //line
    }
```